# To calculate the flux of water through a parabolic cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

> If velocity vector is given as $\mathbf F=y\mathbf i +2 \mathbf j+\mathbf k$ , then find the flux of water through the parabolic cylinder $y=x^2$, $0\le x\le 3$, $0\le z \le 3$.

For this problem I think we need to construct a 3-dimensional graph on paper and then find the surface integral but I’m having an issue finding the unit normal vectors and in the whole integration process.

Answer (score 0):

The surface can be parameterzied by x and z

$S = (x, x^2, z)\\
dS = \frac{dS}{dx} \times \frac{dS}{dz} = (2x,-1,0)\\
F = (x^2,2,1)\\
$

$\iint F\cdot dS = \int_0^3\int_0^3 2x^3-2 \, dx \, dz$

Think you can get home from there?

Comment: dS = (dS/dx) x (dS/dz) . how did you arrive at this equation ?

Comment: It is pretty standard stuff for surface integrals.  If you mark a little box on the $xz$ plane that is $dx \times dz$ in dimensions, and you look at the surface above the plane, what is the area of the surface above the box?  You look a how $dx$ and $dz$ project onto the plane ($dS/dx$, and $dS/dz$), and you calculate $(dS/dx)(dS/dz) \sin\theta$ which also happens to be the cross product of those vectors.